# Unable to implement Google sign up for android

Tags: android

Tried implementing Google sign up for android app, the code is as below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    //Signin button
    private SignInButton signInButton;

    //Signing Options
    private GoogleSignInOptions gso;

    //google api client
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    //Signin constant to check the activity result
    private int RC_SIGN_IN = 100;

    //TextViews
    private TextView textViewName;
    private TextView textViewEmail;
    private NetworkImageView profilePhoto;

    //Image Loader
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Initializing Views
        textViewName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        textViewEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewEmail);
        profilePhoto = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.profileImage);

        //Initializing google signin option
        gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        //Initializing signinbutton
        signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        signInButton.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_WIDE);
        signInButton.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());

        //Initializing google api client
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();


        //Setting onclick listener to signing button
        signInButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    //This function will option signing intent
    private void signIn() {
        //Creating an intent
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);

        //Starting intent for result
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        //If signin
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            //Calling a new function to handle signin
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }


    //After the signing we are calling this function
    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        //If the login succeed
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            //Getting google account
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

            //Displaying name and email
            textViewName.setText(acct.getDisplayName());
            textViewEmail.setText(acct.getEmail());


        } else {
            //If login fails
            Toast.makeText(this, "Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == signInButton) {
            //Calling signin
            signIn();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

I have rechecked all the prerequisites as per the google directives but I am getting a login failed toast as the `result.isSuccess()` is `false` again and again. I have seen many people wondering with this error but no clear solution anywhere. Is there something obvious I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not connecting the `GoogleApiClient`. Acc to the docs [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient):

> You should instantiate a client object in your Activity's
>   `onCreate(Bundle)` method and then call `connect()` in `onStart()` and
>   `disconnect()` in `onStop()`, regardless of the state.

So, you need to `connect()` and subsequently `disconnect()` the `GoogleApiClient`.

Comment: Tried implementing that still getting the same result.

Comment: Have you tried looking through the logs to see why is it failing? Usually, there are logs that are printed when there is an error. @gunner

Comment: there are no errors being shown in the log 

05-06 23:31:38.090  29036-29066/app.num.googleintegration I/GMPM﹕ Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
05-06 23:31:38.232  29036-29036/app.num.googleintegration D/SignInActivity﹕ handleSignInResult:false
05-06 23:31:38.232  29036-29036/app.num.googleintegration D/AppTracker﹕ App Event: start
05-06 23:31:38.279  29036-29036/app.num.googleintegration D/AbstractTracker﹕ Event success
05-06 23:31:38.279  29036-29036/app.num.googleintegration I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@1380514d time:29261787

Comment: it seems that there is no problem with the code because I have directly taken the google code as well as many codes through various tutorials, I am not getting any error but the code is not getting a response from the server. It even asks permission pop up but then handleSignInResult:false. Is there something missing in the google code as I have seen this issue on many forums but nowhere it is solved

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create the signed APK for this. Make sure that you use a different SHA key for release. Then generate the APK and directly install it on your phone. It should work that way.

Comment: yeah Thanks or your answer. Something similar has been suggested in the link posted by nerd in the comments. However that link does not say about a different SHA.. let me look into this.